# convert pdf (with special characters) to text

Tags: r, pdf, text, text-analysis

Hi I'm trying to convert multiple pdfs to text, my code is working, however most of mine file are in spanish, with characters such as (ñ,í,ó,ú,é) and these (ñ,í,ó,ú,é) are getting corrupted. Also I need the text file to be in lower case for text analysis later:

```
library(XML)
  library(httr)
  library(dplyr)
  library(tidyr)
  library(stringr)
  library(tm)

  # Get a list of all of the document names of the downloaded PDFs
    pdf_files <- list.files(path = paste(getwd(), '/pdf', sep = ''),
                            pattern = 'pdf',
                            full.names = TRUE)

    # Check there are pdf files in directory
    if( length(pdf_files) > 0 ){

      # Loop through each PDF and create a txt version in the same folder

      for(i in pdf_files){

        system(
          paste(
            paste('"', getwd(), '/dependencies/xpdf/bin64/pdftotext.exe"', sep = ''), 
            paste0('"', i, '"')),
          wait = FALSE)

      }
    }


  cat( '\nConversion to text complete.\n\n' )
```

Comment: Could you detail how the text gets corrupted? Or show examples of expected text vs corrupted text?

Comment: TEXT "El crecimiento dramático de las remesas internacionales. Este fenómeno, durante décadas, es hoy de máxima actualidad y millones de familias en países."  I'M GETTING  El crecimiento dram·tico de las remesas internacionales. Este fenÛmeno, durante dÈcadas, es hoy de m·xima actualidad y millones de familias en paÌses.

Comment: Judging from your example the encoding used to create the PDF may be faulty and therefore recovery of the correct Unicode characters not (easily) possible. Have you tried using a command line tool like `pdftotext` from the Poppler project to check whether its output shows the correct characters?

Comment: you probably need to set `-enc [encoding-name]` for pdftotext.exe, default is probably "Latin1", you probably need UTF-8

Comment: Can you give a link to a PDF which has this problem?